# SonarQube is unable to analyze file: bridge method not marked as synthetic

Tags: java, sonarqube, spring-aop, java-synthetic-methods

I've got this exception when analyzing a project with SonarQube (the project utilizes JavaFX, Spring, AOP with compile-time weaving). 
I'm using the maven plugin to run the analysis sonar:sonar but I get the same errors with a Jenkins plugin.
I'm running the sonar plugin on a super-pom used with maven's reactor plugin.
What are my solutions?

```
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project [...]-gui-product: SonarQube is unable to analyze fil
        e : '[...]ConfigurationController.java': bridge method not
        marked as synthetic in class com/[...]/core/domain/events/DomainEvent -> [Help 1]
        org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project [...]
        -gui-product: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\projects\[...]gui\application\controller\
        ConfigurationController.java'
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\projects\[...]application\controller\ConfigurationController.java'
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
        Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'D:\projects\[...]\ConfigurationController.java'
        at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:114)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.scan(AstScanner.java:75)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:122)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:115)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:92)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:122)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:222)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:223)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:52)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:128)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:171)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
        ... 22 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: bridge method not marked as synthetic in class com/[...]core/domain/events/DomainEvent
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:145)
        at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeVisitor.visitMethod(BytecodeVisitor.java:204)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:911)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:693)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
        at org.sonar.java.resolve.BytecodeCompleter.complete(BytecodeCompleter.java:100)
        at org.sonar.java.resolve.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:98)
        at org.sonar.java.resolve.Type.getSymbol(Type.java:69)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.InstanceOfAlwaysTrueCheck.typeInherits(InstanceOfAlwaysTrueCheck.java:62)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.InstanceOfAlwaysTrueCheck.visitNode(InstanceOfAlwaysTrueCheck.java:49)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:95)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:73)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:67)
        at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:122)
        at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.walkAndVisit(AstWalker.java:67)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:107)
        ... 59 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project does '*AOP with compile-time weaving*', so you might be impacted by this AspectJ bug:

- [Bug #467415](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=467415) - *Weaver created bridge methods missing ACC_SYNTHETIC* - fixed in AspectJ v1.8.6

It causes flags in bytecode to be incorrect (i.e. *bridge* methods missing the *Synthetic* flag), so when that same bytecode is visited by the SonarQube Java Plugin, it fails accordingly: '*bridge method not marked as synthetic*'.